# Easy linux permissions inquiry

Tags: linux

I want to give a certain user full rwx permission on a directory (recursively), including any files or subdirectories that may be created in the future. I do NOT want to make them the owner of that directory. What syntax should I use? Thanks - Debbie

Answer (score 1):

You've got two choices:

a) the user is in the group that owns the directory tree

- use group permission: `chmod -R g+rwx thedir`

b) the user is NOT in the group that owns the directory tree

- use the "Everyone else" permission flagS: `chmod -R o+rwx thedir`

Answer (score 0):

Because you want newly created files and directories in this tree to follow the same rule you need

```
   $ chgrp thegrp thedir
   $ chmod g+rwxs thedir
```